# Font seems blurry when I increase the font-weight of the container

Tags: html, css

I was wondering why when I specify the font-weight of an element, it works correctly, but it looks kind of blurry when i give a font-weight attribute to its container.
I have this piece of code where I noticed this:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;500&display=swap');
```

```html
<style>
  html {
    font-family: "Roboto";
  }
  
  #welcome-section {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-weight: 500; <--- If you delete this line, you will see what I mean
  }
</style>

<html>
<section id="welcome-section">
  <h1>Hello, I'm Pablo!</h1>
</section>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not blurry it's bold too much.

Comment: If  you look in your browser dev tools you can inspect who is setting what weights and sizes of the text.

Comment: It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTHaW.png). Not blurry.

Answer (score 1):

**Here try this code**

```css
  html {
    font-family: "Roboto";
  }

  #welcome-section {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  h1 {
    font-weight: 500!important; <--- If you delete this line, you will see what I mean
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <h1>Hello, I'm Pablo!</h1>
  </section>
</html>
```

**Verify my answer if it work for you.**

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Roboto-bold, Roboto-Medium, Roboto-Regular, Roboto-light, Roboto-Thin these fonts don't be blurry you can download that form [this link in google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto)